# How to check if the lat/lon of a selected area lies within the range defined in a database using Java

Tags: java, postgresql, openlayers

I have a map where OpenLayers is used to render the map. By selecting a region on the map, we find the lat/lon values of the selected region. I have data in a database which defines the lat/lon values of a certain vehicle. I want to check whether the vehicle lies within the area I have selected on the map. How would I do this in Java?

```
(function () {
    var map, drawControls, boxLayer;

    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

        var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {
            layers: 'basic'
        });


        boxLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Box layer");

        map.addLayers([wmsLayer, boxLayer]);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

        var box = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(boxLayer,
        OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
            handlerOptions: {
                sides: 4,
                irregular: true
            },

            callbacks: {
                up: function (geom) {
                    console.log(geom);
                    alert(geom);
                }
            }
        });

        map.addControl(box);
        box.activate();


        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);

    }

    init();

})();
```

[Jsfiddle to select a region on map](http://jsfiddle.net/7S6Lf/6/)

The above fiddle selects a region on the map and I have a Postgres database which has a table track_vehicle with columns vehicle_id, latitude and longitude. I want to check whether the latitude  and longitude of the vehicle lie within the range selected on the map using Java.

Comment: This will require a) Get the map zoom area from Javascript b) send the area server side to Java c) Execute a query on the DB c) send the vehicle position back to client (if inside the area) d) show the vehicle back to map with openLayers. Are you sure this is what you want, because it will not be efficient

Comment: What is the question? How to do the spatial query, how to send the data back?

Comment: On second read: You keep saying 'Java' but your code looks like 'JavaScript'. You are aware that these are different languages, do you?

Comment: @Alexandros : Sir exactly I want to do the same. But I just want to send the vehicle ID to my jsp page if vehicle is in the region selected. It is not necessary to send it to map with openlayers as mentioned by you in the last step.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer : Sir Yes I am aware they are two different languages. I have just given the map code here. But to check the latitude and longitude against db I will need java if I am not wrong.

Comment: @Vidya Then you should provide the relevant code. Currently its like asking the doctor to see your hand because your foot aches. Show what you have and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude are numbers (positives indicating east / south, negatives indicating west / north) so you can check if a point lies within an area by using greater than and smaller than operations.

So `66° 33′ 39″ N` becomes `66033039` while `66° 33′ 39″ S` becomes `-66033039`. Just write every step as three digit integer and you will always end with a nine digit number.

```
public int degreesToInt(int degrees, int minutes, int seconds) {
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000");
    return Integer.valueOf(nf.format(degrees) +
                           nf.format(minutes) +
                           nf.format(seconds));
}

public boolean objectInArea(int vehicleLatitude, int vehicleLongitude,
                            int northLatitudeBorder, int southLatitudeBorder,
                            int westLongitudeBorder, int eastLongitudeBorder) {
    if(westLongitudeBorder > eastLongitudeBorder) {
       return objectInArea(vehicleLatitude, vehicleLongitude,
                           northLatitudeBorder, southLatitudeBorder, 
                           -180000000,eastLongitudeBorder) ||
              objectInArea(vehicleLatitude, vehicleLongitude,
                           northLatitudeBorder, southLatitudeBorder, 
                           westLongitudeBorder,180000000);
    }
    return vehicleLongitude < eastLongitudeBorder &&
           vehicleLongitude > westLongitudeBorder &&
           vehicleLatitude < southLatitudeBorder &&
           vehicleLatitude > northLatitudeBorder;
}
```

You might ask: "Why three digits and not two?"

1. It has no drawbacks.
2. You can read the numbers easier as minutes and seconds never have a hundreds digit so there will always be a zero, which makes debugging easier.
3. You can employ the same conversion to degrees (east/west have more than 100 degrees) as to minutes and seconds as well.